# How to print a list of ggplots in Shiny in a for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want something like this to happen in Shiny (but just 1 plot, not 4):

[image]

THe following steps are the ones that I want for my Shiny app plot:

1. Print an empty plot
2. Draw the red abline
3. Sequentially draw **n** segments with points
4. Draw blue dotted abline
5. Stop

But I got 2 problems with my function that I don't know how to fix:

1. In the slider "n", for example if I put 10, and press "Correr", I get 8 segments first, I want none at first, and when I press the "play" button the pattern I wrote above starts.
2. Again, say I put 10, as soon as the blue dotted abline appears, I get an error of "subscript out of bounds"

**ui:**

```
ui <-fluidPage(
    
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Simulacion 1",
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         sliderInput(inputId = "a",label = "a",value = 1 ,min = 1,max = 20),
                         sliderInput(inputId = "b",label = "b",value = 1 ,min = 1,max= 20),
                         sliderInput(inputId = "sig",label = "sig",value = 1 ,min = 1,max=50),
                         sliderInput(inputId = "n",label = "n",value = 1 ,min = 1,max=50,step=1,animate=animationOptions(interval=1000)),
                         actionButton(inputId= "correr", label = "Correr")),
                     mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "simul1")
                     )))),)
```

**server:**

```
server <-function(input, output) {
    z=qnorm(0.975)
    intercepto=c()
    pendiente=c()
    
    
    
    sim.beta=function(a,b,sig,n){
        x=runif(n,1,10)
        y=a+b*x+rnorm(n,0,sig)  
        return(data.frame(x,y))
    }
    Animacion=eventReactive(input$correr,{
        set.seed(123)
            s1=sim.beta(input$a,input$b,input$sig,input$n)
            grafico=vector('list', ncol(s1))
            
            X=s1$x;Y=s1$y
            mod1=lm(s1$y~s1$x)
            r11=X;r21=input$a+input$b*r11
            
           
            for (i in 1:c(input$n+3)) {
                if(i==1){
                    grafico[[i]]=ggplot(s1,aes(x,y))+
                        theme_classic()+
                        xlim(0,10)+
                        ylim(input$a-z*input$sig,2*input$a+input$b*10+z*input$sig)
                }
                if(i==2){
                    grafico[[i]]=grafico[[i-1]]+
                        geom_abline(intercept = input$a,slope = input$b,col=2)
                }
                else if(i>2 & i<=c(input$n+2)){
                    grafico[[i]]= local({
                        i=i
                        ggplot(s1[1:c(i-2),],aes(x,y))+
                            theme_classic()+
                            xlim(0,10)+
                            ylim(input$a-z*input$sig,2*input$a+input$b*10+z*input$sig)+
                            geom_abline(intercept = input$a,slope = input$b,col=2)+
                            geom_segment(aes(x=r11[1:c(i-2)],y=r21[1:c(i-2)]+z*input$sig,xend=r11[1:c(i-2)],yend=r21[1:c(i-2)]-z*input$sig),linetype=2)+
                            geom_point(aes(X[1:c(i-2)],Y[1:c(i-2)]),col=3,size=3)
                    })
                }
                else if(i==c(input$n+3)){
                    grafico[[i]]= grafico[[i-1]]+
                        geom_abline(aes(intercept=mod1$coefficients[1],slope=mod1$coefficients[2]),col=4,linetype=2)
                    
                }
                
                
            }
            
            grafico
            
        
    })
    
    output$simul1 <- renderPlot({
        Animacion()[[input$n]]
    }, height = 650, width = 650)
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution. I've made a few changes:

- `animacion` is now only dependent on a `reactiveTimer`. This allows you to generate new plot data in a given interval
- `animacion` only returns one plot, which is then plotted -> you don't need to mess around with `input$n` which plot should be shown
- I've added some logic to introduce a timer counter/index, so that the correct output data is sequentially generated
- because the parameter change should only applied when "Correr" is pressed, I've added a new `eventReactive` to store the parameters (otherwise the updated values would be automatically used every time the timer triggers)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <-fluidPage(
    
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Simulacion 1",
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         sliderInput(inputId = "a",label = "a",value = 1 ,min = 1,max = 20),
                         sliderInput(inputId = "b",label = "b",value = 1 ,min = 1,max= 20),
                         sliderInput(inputId = "sig",label = "sig",value = 1 ,min = 1,max=50),
                         sliderInput(inputId = "n",label = "n",value = 1 ,min = 1,max=50,step=1,animate=animationOptions(interval=1000)),
                         actionButton(inputId= "correr", label = "Correr")),
                     mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "simul1")
                     )))))

server <-function(input, output) {
    z=qnorm(0.975)
    intercepto=c()
    pendiente=c()
    
    animation_timer <- reactiveTimer(1500)
    timer_index <- 1
    grafico <- list()
    
    
    
    sim.beta=function(a,b,sig,n){
        x=runif(n,1,10)
        y=a+b*x+rnorm(n,0,sig)  
        return(data.frame(x,y))
    }
    
    animation_parameters <- eventReactive(input$correr, {
        list(a = input$a,
             b = input$b,
             sig = input$sig,
             n = input$n)
    })
    
    
    
    Animacion = eventReactive(animation_timer(),{
        set.seed(123)
        s1=sim.beta(animation_parameters()$a,
                    animation_parameters()$b,
                    animation_parameters()$sig,
                    animation_parameters()$n)
        
        X=s1$x;Y=s1$y
        mod1=lm(s1$y~s1$x)
        r11=X;r21=input$a+input$b*r11
        
        
        
            if(timer_index ==1){
                grafico <<- ggplot(s1,aes(x,y))+
                    theme_classic()+
                    xlim(0,10)+
                    ylim(animation_parameters()$a-z*animation_parameters()$sig,2*animation_parameters()$a+animation_parameters()$b*10+z*animation_parameters()$sig)
            }
            if(timer_index ==2){
                grafico <<- grafico +
                    geom_abline(intercept = animation_parameters()$a,slope = animation_parameters()$b,col=2)
            }
            else if(timer_index>2 & timer_index<=c(animation_parameters()$n+2)){
                grafico <<- local({
                    i= timer_index
                    ggplot(s1[1:c(i-2),],aes(x,y))+
                        theme_classic()+
                        xlim(0,10)+
                        ylim(animation_parameters()$a-z*animation_parameters()$sig,2*animation_parameters()$a+animation_parameters()$b*10+z*animation_parameters()$sig)+
                        geom_abline(intercept = animation_parameters()$a,slope = animation_parameters()$b,col=2)+
                        geom_segment(aes(x=r11[1:c(i-2)],y=r21[1:c(i-2)]+z*animation_parameters()$sig,xend=r11[1:c(i-2)],yend=r21[1:c(i-2)]-z*animation_parameters()$sig),linetype=2)+
                        geom_point(aes(X[1:c(i-2)],Y[1:c(i-2)]),col=3,size=3)
                })
            }
            else if(timer_index ==c(animation_parameters()$n+3)){
                grafico <<-  grafico +
                    geom_abline(aes(intercept=mod1$coefficients[1],slope=mod1$coefficients[2]),col=4,linetype=2)
                
            }
            
            
        
        
        
        # update timer_index
        if (timer_index == animation_parameters()$n + 3) {
            timer_index <<- 1
        } else {
        timer_index <<- timer_index + 1
        }
        
        grafico
        
    })
    
    output$simul1 <- renderPlot({
        Animacion()
    }, height = 650, width = 650)
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

P.S. I'm actually not sure if `local` and `animation_parameters` work together, maybe you have to tweak that.