# Implementing a reactive expression with time depentent data for a plot

Tags: r, shiny

I'm programming a shiny app and I want to use reactive expressions, like mentioned and explained in the tutorial - https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/

In the paragraph "Streamline computation" and the consecutive one "Reactive expressions" there is a manner described to update your data, when your processing data changes.

This I want to apply in my shiny app, but my trials failed...

This is my function, where I'm able to do my wanted procedure. As you can see the lines(x.v,y) becomes updated and also plotted. That's my aim.

```
# The vector x.v of my line to plot
x.v=c(1)

# y values of my line to plot
y=c(seq(from=1,to=70,length.out=30))

# the in crement variable
i=2

# time variable for calculating the data update
time=round(unname(proc.time()[3]),2)
#print(time)

# Open a device with an empty plot
plot(0,0,col="white",type="l",xlim=c(0,120),ylim=c(0,90))


while(TRUE) {

    # stopping criterion
    if (length(x.v)==length(y)) break

    # Incrementing i and adding the i value to vector x.v
    if(round(unname(proc.time()[3]),2)-time>=0.1) {
        time=round(unname(proc.time()[3]),2)
        x.v=c(x.v,i)
        i=i+1
        #print(x.v)

        # adding the lines to the plot
        lines(x.v[(length(x.v)-1):length(x.v)],y[(length(x.v)-1):length(x.v)])
    } 
}
```

For your convenience a simple shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   
sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(

 # Group of checkboxes
  checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Checkbox group"),
    choices = list("Choice 1" = 1),
    selected = 1)

),

mainPanel(


    plotOutput("plot_Choice1")


)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {


    output$plot_Choice1=renderPlot({
        req(input$checkGroup)
        if (any(input$checkGroup == 1)) {
            # Here I need your help.
            # How can I convert the above montioned code to get it in an appropirate way for shiny?
        }
    })

 

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Can you please help me to convert this code sequence to a shiny reactive expression? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can use my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636698/how-to-print-a-list-of-ggplots-in-shiny-in-a-for-loop/63639944#63639944) as a starting point or try to port your code to `gganimate`

Comment: @starja: the background to my question is, that I have a database which is filled up by time. So I need to update my plotting data at distinct timesteps... gganimate is a nice tool, but not that what I want. At this point my question is a little bit foggy. Sorry for that...